# How to remove old indexes without recreating them all in mongoose js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have multiple models in my mongoDB database and I need to be able to sync the indexes with the models indexes (add or remove indexes to the database) without removing the previous indexes.
Currently the way I have found to do this is running `dropIndexes()` and then `syncIndexes()` for every model on my db, but the problem is that this destroys info about how good are the indexes performing in mongo Atlas. Atlas monitors the indexes created and gives you feedback about how good or bad your indexes are, but this needs about a week to give me some info and everytime I run the commands above the timer restarts.

I know that setting the configuration 'useCreateIndex' allows you to add new indexes to the db when added to your models, but I can't find a way to remove them when eliminated from the model.

I am using node 14.18.2 and mongoose 5.12.0

Comment: "_the problem is that this destroys info about how good are the indexes performing_" - can you elaborate more about what this means and more specifically about what underlying problem you're trying to avoid/fix?